# if-else condition not working correctly in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing a procedure to delete department from a table. It takes depatment id as argument and delete the department with given id. but it is not working correctly.When i didnot use EXCEPTION, it only give output when gien department id is present in table but if the id is not present in table it throw error. When i use exception, It did not check the if else condition.
Here is my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE del_job(j_id number) IS
   jj_id  bb_department.iddepartment%type; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT IDDEPARTMENT 
   INTO jj_id
   FROM BB_DEPARTMENT
   WHERE IDDEPARTMENT=j_id; 
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        jj_id := NULL;
   IF (jj_id=j_id) THEN 
      DELETE FROM BB_DEPARTMENT
      WHERE IDDEPARTMENT=j_id;
       dbms_output.put_line ('Job Deleted'); 
    ELSIF(jj_id=0) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('No Job Deleted'); 
   END IF; 
END; 
/
```

Comment: You don't even need the SELECT to see if the department exists.  Just issue the DELETE.  If the department exits, it will be deleted.  If it does not exist, that's what you wanted your end point to be anyway, so no harm no foul.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation seems to imply that you want your `if` statement to be part of the normal flow rather than part of the `exception` block.  But your actual code has the `if` statement in the exception handler.  Since you're assigning a `null` to `jj_id` in the exception handler before running the `if` statement and `null` is never equal to nor unequal to any value, neither your `if` nor your `elsif` clause can ever be true so neither `dbms_output` call will be made.

Assuming your indentation shows your actual intent, my guess is that you want a nested PL/SQL block for the `select` statement and exception handler.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE del_job(j_id number) IS
   jj_id  bb_department.iddepartment%type; 
BEGIN 
   BEGIN
      SELECT IDDEPARTMENT 
      INTO jj_id
      FROM BB_DEPARTMENT
      WHERE IDDEPARTMENT=j_id; 
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        jj_id := NULL;
   END;

   IF (jj_id=j_id) THEN 
      DELETE FROM BB_DEPARTMENT
      WHERE IDDEPARTMENT=j_id;
       dbms_output.put_line ('Job Deleted'); 
    ELSIF(jj_id=0) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('No Job Deleted'); 
   END IF; 
END; 
/
```

Comment: I just want a procedure that shows output "Job Deleted" department id is present in table and shows "No Job Deleted" When department id is not present in table.

Comment: @AAA - If you want to print "No Job Deleted" if `j_id` is not present in the table, your `elsif` condition doesn't make sense.  If there is no row in the table, `jj_id` is being assigned a value of `null`.  Yet you're checking to see if it has a value of `0`.  If you always want one of the two statements to be printed, you should just have an `else` clause rather than an `elsif` clause.

Comment: I also use that but it doesn't work and give an error.                                                  Error starting at line : 21 in command -
BEGIN DEL_JOB(1); END;
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.DEL_JOB", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

Comment: **a)** Code Justin posted can't return NO_DATA_FOUND as he *handles* it. **b)** Error says `... SYSTEM.DEL_JOB ...`. **SYSTEM**? You'd rather not create your objects in such a schema. Don't you have any other? SYS and SYSTEM are special, they *own* the database. If you do something wrong & unexpected, expect that you'll *destroy* the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things overly difficult. `DELETE` sets sql%rowcount to the number of rows processed. So there is no need to select the department; just delete the appropriate id. If you want a confirmation message then test sql%rowcount. If the row was deleted it will contain 1 (or greater), if the id did not exist it will contain 0. Print the appropriate message.

```
create or replace procedure del_job(j_id number) is 
begin 
    delete 
      from bb_department
     where iddepartment=j_id; 
      
     if sql%rowcount > 0 then 
        dbms_output.put_line ('Job Deleted'); 
     else 
        dbms_output.put_line ('No Job Deleted'); 
     end if; 
end del_job; 
/
```